# Sitecore not resolving index properties to corresponding solr field names (with suffix)

Tags: solr

I have a single line field in Sitecore, (I see same issue for other field types too). I am trying to do a SOLR search on this field.
I created a search result class

```
public class SearchResult : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("page_heading")]
    public string PageName { get; set; }
}
```

In the index, I see the field as expected page_heading_t with corresponding values on it.

[image]

But when I do a search on this field, using the above property, I dont see results, and in the search log, I see:

[image]

When I run this same query in solr, after appending the _t suffix to the fields, I see results as expected:

[image]

However, the suffix is not getting appended as expected on the query generated by the code.
Any ideas?

I have verified that this field exists only on 1 template on the instance (which is used as the base template on multiple templates)

Comment: What does your configuration setting look like for the new field? Perhaps the returnType needs to be set.

Comment: Is this an upgrade or a custom SOLR index? Your configs seem to be off since the your fields are not being transformed into the right field names.

Comment: Its a single line text - built in field - does that answer the question? I am using a custom index - but it uses the default solr configuration.

Comment: It is not an upgrade, and I am on Sitecore 9.2

Comment: @DurgaBose, are you adding the field in the index by specifying it in the section <include hint="list:AddIncludedField"> or is the <indexAllFields> set to true?